# Windows 7 installer installs system flag on a different hard disk

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have two hard disks (disk 0 and disk 2) - both are clean and unformatted. When I try to install Windows 7 on disk 0, it places the "system" flag on disk 2, hence I am unable to clean disk 2 using diskpart as it says disk 2 has a system partition on it.

Without removing disk 2 physically, how can I install all of the OS on just disk 0?

I used <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> and manually created partitions on both disks but it still manages to put the system flag on disk 2, not on disk 0 where the OS actually resides.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience the easiest way is to physically disconnect the second hard drive during installation. I suppose it should not be that much of a problem. Doing so will ensure 100% that your second disk remains intact.

Comment: Thats what I did before, but this is on a laptop whose cover is quite a challenge to remove. I was hoping there was a better solution than prying the cover open.

Comment: It might be possible to disable the hard drive in the Bios of your laptop. Do you know how to access you laptop's bios?

Comment: Already tried, no option to disable a drive

Comment: there are two options. search the web on how to disable a drive in bios or how to use command line interface options inwindows installation